# Conversion of Azure Function to serverless Function

Tags: azure-functions, serverless, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Function App with the following code:

```
        public class JTFunction
        {
           [FunctionName("JT")]
           public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%jtSchedule%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
           {            
            await ProcessJobsAsync();            
           }
        }

        public async Task ProcessJobsAsync()
        {
            var jobs = GetJobsAsync(SyncStatus.Idle);

            var runningJobs = new List<SyncJob>();
            var failedJobs = new List<SyncJob>();
            var startedTasks = new List<Task>();
            await foreach (var job in jobs)
            {
                var groupName = await GetGroupNameAsync(job.TargetOfficeGroupId);

                if (job.LastRunTime == DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(0))
                {
                   await SendMailAsync(message);
                }
                job.RunId = _graphGroupRepository.RunId = Guid.NewGuid();
                _loggingRepository.SyncJobProperties = job.ToDictionary();

                if (await CanWriteToGroup(job))
                {                    
                    startedTasks.Add(_serviceBusTopicsRepository.AddMessageAsync(job));
                    runningJobs.Add(job);
                }
                else
                {
                    job.Enabled = false;
                    failedJobs.Add(job);
                }                

                _loggingRepository.SyncJobProperties = null;
            }
            startedTasks.Add(UpdateSyncJobStatusAsync(runningJobs, SyncStatus.InProgress));
            startedTasks.Add(UpdateSyncJobStatusAsync(failedJobs, SyncStatus.Error));
            await Task.WhenAll(startedTasks);

            foreach (var failedJob in failedJobs)
            {                
                await SendMailAsync(message);
            }
        }
```

How do I convert this to a serverless function?

Comment: Azure Functions are serverless functions. Please explain what you are trying to do more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom W said in the comment, azure function is a classic serverless service.

Have a look of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview).

Azure function is not specific to a machine, and its instances may be on different machines.